# How does alexa know all these information?

Tags: privacy, alexa

http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com#

Under Audience tab, how does alexa knows information on gender, education, age, has child...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some info can be found here:

- [http://www.alexa.com/help/traffic_learn_more](http://web.archive.org/web/20111228211533/https://www.alexa.com/help/traffic_learn_more)

> The traffic rank is based on three months of aggregated historical traffic data from millions of Alexa Toolbar users and data obtained from other, diverse traffic data sources, and is a combined measure of page views and users (reach). As a first step, Alexa computes the reach and number of page views for all sites on the Web on a daily basis. The main Alexa traffic rank is based on a value derived from these two quantities averaged over time (so that the rank of a site reflects both the number of users who visit that site as well as the number of pages on the site viewed by those users). The three-month change is determined by comparing the site's current rank with its rank from three months ago. For example, on July 1, the three-month change would show the difference between the rank based on traffic during the first quarter of the year and the rank based on traffic during the second quarter.

Comment: +1 ;) There's a reason those toolbars come with a performance hit to surfing the web. They're spying on you.

Comment: Do they get info only with the toolbar? If so, their results are probably skewed against privacy-savvy users. *ToolbarHaters.org* will get a rank inferior to *WeLoveToolbars.biz*